# xpath on simplexml object returns nothing

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have the following XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<q:quakeml xmlns="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/bed/1.2" xmlns:q="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/quakeml/1.2" xmlns:catalog="http://anss.org/xmlns/catalog/0.1">
    <eventParameters publicID="static">
        <event catalog:eventsource="rt">
        </event>
        <event catalog:eventsource="rt">
        </event>
        <event catalog:eventsource="rt">
        </event>
    </eventParameters>
</q:quakeml>
```

I am using the following code which builds a simplexml object and attempts to extract all the event objects using an xpath query:

```
$se = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$se->registerXPathNamespace('q', 'http://quakeml.org/xmlns/quakeml/1.2');
$se->registerXPathNamespace('c', 'http://anss.org/xmlns/catalog/0.1');
$events = $se->xpath('//event');
```

Obviously this does not work but what am I doing wrong. How to fetch all event objects from this structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a default namespace for your document (`xmlns="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/bed/1.2"`) you will need to register that and use a prefix to all elements which don't have a specific namespace prefix...

```
$se->registerXPathNamespace('d', 'http://quakeml.org/xmlns/bed/1.2');
$events = $se->xpath('//d:event');
```

I tend to use `d` - but you can use anything as long as you use the same thing in your XPath.